# ¿Cómo actualizar el valor de un input arrojado de una variable echo?

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

Tengo el siguiente código para que me lanze desde un 'value' un 'echo' puesto en 'php':

```
<input type="text" name="clave" id="clave" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off" value="
        <?php
        $logitud = 8;
        $clave = substr( md5(microtime()), 1, $logitud);
        echo $clave;
        ?>"
```

/>

Cada vez que recargo este me genera un nuevo código en el 'input', lo que quiero es que esto me lo genere automáticamente, es decir, sin recargar la página.

ATTE: Este input es para hacerlo hidden y no editable, esto no es necesario que me lo explique.....

Comment: Para modificar un sitio sin recargar necesitas usar javascript. ¿Tienes nociones de esto?

Comment: Con php es imposible, debes hacer como dice @Jonathan Orta, pero si necesitas la variable de php ve a buscarla con ajax

Comment: Se que puede hacer con javascript pero ¿Cómo? esa es mi duda, solo quiero actualizar esa variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya no es necesario ya encontre el metodo aqui se los dejo para aquellos que quieran respuesta
De tanto buscar logre adaptar el script a mis ideas la cual es generar automaticamente unas letras que funcionan como clave dichas letras se generan automaticamente con el script y me los guarda

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function recargar(){   
var variable_post="Mi texto recargado";
$.post("miscript.php", { variable: variable_post }, function(data){
    //// Verificamos la rpta entregada por miscript.php
    if (data>10) {
        $("#recargado").html(data);
    } else {
        $("#recargado").html(data);
    }  
}); 
setTimeout("recargar()",10,1)       
}
</script>
```

En el body coloque

```
onload="javascript:recargar();"
```

Y simplemente invoco un h3 para que muestre los resultados

```
<h3 name="clave" autocomplete="off" value="" id="recargado"/></h3>
```

Como ven en la funcion llamo al archivo miscript.php que contiene lo siguiente

```
<?php 
$logitud = 8;
$clave = substr( md5(microtime()), 1, $logitud);
echo $clave;?>
```